# How free is basic English word order in poetry

Tags: word-order

I understand that basic English word order is strictly SVO, and alternate word orders are extremely rare, if not nonexistent, in regular speech and prose. In poetry, however, can this be broken? So would a sentence like

“Holds the chest his treasures.”

Or

“The chests his treasures hold.”

Be correct sentences in poetry? Just to be clear, I am not talking about sentences where the object is moved to the front and separated by a comma, like

“His treasures, the chests hold.”

As these kind of sentences I know already to be normal and used, but I don’t feel like this is truly OSV since it is separated by a comma, and it is just a regular SVO sentence with the object moved to the front for emphasis.

Comment: You can do any word order you like in poetry, and many poets (especially in the last 100 years) have played around with grammar or entirely ignored traditional rules. We can't tell you how to write poetry. You might be better posting on writing.stackexchange.com as this is a question about literary technique not conventional English usage.

Comment: Your poetry might be read in a Yoda voice if this too often you do. But yes, word order can (arguably) sometimes solve rhyming or meter challenges in poetry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as other comments have said, poetry often pays scant heed to the standard usages covered on ELU. And doubtless different poetic genres have different respect for standard rules.

Comment: I see, so in poetry, anything goes . . .

Comment: There are no defined rules for word order in poetry ... look at e e cummings's poetry if you want to see some wonderful poems where the syntax has been stretched to and beyond the breaking point. But "the chests his treasures hold" woudn't be out of the ordinary, while "holds the chest his treasure" would stand out as unusual syntax (and "of gold and diamonds holds the chest his treasure" might make a reader pause and think and possibly just give up on the entire poem).

Comment: @PeterShor and still be grammatically acceptable.

Comment: John Keats, in his *Ode on Melancholy*, uses "Or if thy mistress some rich anger shows," the same word order as "The chests his treasures hold." Is that grammatically acceptable in ordinary prose? I don't know, but it's quite rare.